# Why isn't the hex value C181 rendered as capital A in UTF-8?

Tags: utf-8

A two-byte UTF-8 character provides 11 bits for the payload:

```
110x xxxx 10xx xxxx
```

I know this isn't efficient, but why can't that payload be in the lower range, such that 'A'=65?

```
65 decimal = 1000001 binary

two-byte template: 110_ ____ 10__ ____
payload:                   1   00 0001
result:            1100 0001 1000 0001
```

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Overlong_encodings), the standard specifically disallows this. While the algorithm allows you to use more bytes than necessary through zero padding, the standard dictates that there is a one-to-one mapping between code points and encoding byte sequences. An overlong encoding like the one you present is an invalid byte sequence.

Comment: Thank you, lenz. I wish I could mark your comment as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Overlong_encodings), the standard specifically disallows this. While the UTF-8 algorithm allows you to use more bytes than necessary through zero padding, the standard dictates that there is a one-to-one mapping between code points and encoding byte sequences.

An overlong encoding like the one you present is treated as an invalid byte sequence.

Likewise, you aren't allowed to encode code points above `U+10FFFF`, even though the algorithm could get you up to `U+7FFFFFFF`.
You *are* however allowed to encode code points that haven't been assigned (ie. which have no meaning yet).

Answer (score 1):

This is a security risk. Allowing software to interpret "non-shortest form" UTF-8 prevents accurate and efficient string checks. "DROP T[41]BLE" shouldn't be the same as "DROP T[C181]BLE". The problem with such an implementation would be buried if bad UTF-8 gets converted to good UTF-16 before it's used.

http://www.unicode.org/versions/corrigendum1.html

(Special thanks to lenz for pointing me to useful search terms.)